# Input not working in python 3

Tags: python, input

I have been given an assignment by my teacher in class to write a Python program that calculates the circumference and area of certain shapes. So far my first bit of code

```
import math

print ('Circumference and Area calculator')
def loop():
    again = input ('Would you like to make any more calculations? (y/n)').lower()
    if again == "y":
        choice()
    elif again == "n":
            print ('\nGoodbye')
    else:
            print ('Please enter y for yes and n for no')
            print ('Try again')
            loop()
```

But when I run this module in the Python IDLE the input does not show up, and it just prints "Circumference and Area calculator". After removing `def loop():` the input works, but with it it doesn't.

Would any one be able to give a solution or send me on the right path?

Comment: Did you call `loop` function?

Comment: You never invoke the function loop()

Comment: I like how this has an attempt to solve the problem, shows some level of understanding of `python` and requests for `the right path`

Comment: Don't use recursion where a `while` loop would work perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the function loop() but you never call it. You'll want something like this at the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop()
```

Docs on what this does for Python 3 can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `loop` function
Try this:

```
import math

print ('Circumference and Area calculator')
def loop():
    again = input ('Would you like to make any more calculations? (y/n)').lower()
    if again == "y":
        choice()
    elif again == "n":
            print ('\nGoodbye')
    else:
            print ('Please enter y for yes and n for no')
            print ('Try again')
            loop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop()
```